# Why can't I register this method with the PascalScript compiler?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, pascalscript

My question is below.

Here is my setup:

```
interface 

  uses windows, {...,} uPSComponent_Default, uPSComponent, uPSRuntime, uPSComponent_Controls;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    //...
    PSScript1: TPSScript;
    PSImport_Classes1: TPSImport_Classes;
    PSImport_Controls1: TPSImport_Controls;
    procedure PSScript1Compile(Sender: TPSScript);
    //...
  Private
    procedure NewItem(const Caption:string; const SubItems:TStringList);
    //...
  end;

implementation

  {...}

  procedure TForm1.PSScript1Compile(Sender: TPSScript);
  begin
    //...
    Sender.AddMethod(Self, @TForm1.NewItem,  'procedure NewItem(const Caption:string; const SubItems:TStringList);');
    //...
  end;
```

Why am I getting the following error when I try to compile any script.

```
[Error] (1:1): Unable to register function procedure NewItem(const Caption:string; const SubItems:TStringList);
```

I know it has to do with my attempt to import the NewItem method into the PS compiler but I don't know why it will not accept the TStringList.  I know it's the TStringList because if I take out the TStringList param and just use the method with the following signature then everything works.

```
    procedure NewItem(const Caption:string);
```

I can't find any references saying that I can't pass objects back and forth between the compiler/script and my Delphi code but I'm beginning to think that there maybe a limitation in doing exactly this type of thing.

Would it make more sense to try and pass an array of strings instead of a TStringList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were to guess, I'd say it's probably because you haven't registered the TStringList class yet.  Classes have to be registered with PascalScript before it can use them.

Comment: I figured that as well, but shouldn't including the design-time component(s) automatically register the classes contained with in? 
I already have the TPSImport_Classes component on my form I would have thought that would be enough.  What else do I have to do?

Comment: Oh!  I'm not that smart.  I figured it out.  I have to add the design-time components to the PSScript components Plugin List.  
I was adding only my own component to the plugins list because I was using it at runtime only.  It appears that you also have to add the designtime components to the plugins list as well.

Comment: @Ryan: Yeah, "Design time" means "compile time" in this context.